# Cant use Button in styled component,its giving me error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I am using styled-components in js file.When I try to change button colour based on its content its giving me this error:

```
Warning: Prop `className` did not match. Server: "sc-pVTma fSTvVY" Client: "sc-bdvvaa vaKvs"
    at button
    at styled.button (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/issues.js?ts=1617437771165:11202:19599)
    at div
    at Link (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/issues.js?ts=1617437771165:1808:19)

react-dom.development.js:67 Warning: Received `false` for a non-boolean attribute `high`.

If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: high="false" or high={value.toString()}.

If you used to conditionally omit it with high={condition && value}, pass high={condition ? value : undefined} instead.
```

The code for the same is given below for reference":

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
const Button=styled.button`
border:none;
border-radius:10px;
padding:7px 10px;
font-size:12px;
background:${(props) => (props.high ? 'red':'orange')};
color:white;
`
Status:<Button high={card.priority === "high"}>{ card.priority } Priority</Button>
```

Comment: What is the error? All you posted are warnings. Is something not working as expected?

Comment: Yes I want to add background color to button based on the text inside the button.

Comment: Based on this warnings, I couldn't change color of button to red if text inside is "high" else should be orange

Comment: I copy pasted your code into a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cant-use-button-in-styled-component-its-giving-me-error-u8sg8) and it runs without issue. Can you try creating a codesandbox of your own that reproduces the issue you have, and link it in your question so we may live debug it?

Answer (score -1):

This works fine for me. You can match this with your code for debugging.

```
import "./styles.css";
import styled from 'styled-components';
import {useState} from "react";

const Button=styled.button`
  border:none;
  border-radius:10px;
  padding:7px 10px;
  font-size:12px;
  background:${(props) => (props.high ? 'red':'orange')};
  color:white;
`

export default function App() {
  const [priority, setPriority] = useState("High");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Button high={priority === "High"}>{ priority } Priority</Button>
      <button onClick={() => setPriority("Low")}>Low Priority</button>
      <button onClick={() => setPriority("High")}>High Priority</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: If code is running fine and you are simply pointing that out, that should be a comment. What does this resolve as an answer?

Comment: How can I put such long code in the comment? Please tell.

Comment: You don't generally put code in comments. A simple comment that the code is fine is sufficient. If you need code to prove it, then link out to a running and verifiable source that proves the code in question is ok.